# Map class domain

Tags: grails

I have my class domain

```
class domain Factura {
    String name
    BigDecimal value
}
```

in my html:

```
<g:form>
   <input type="text" name="name" />
   <input type="number" step="any" name="value" />
   <inpu type="submit" value="save" />
</g:form>
```

in my controller

```
def save(Factura factura) {
 //Suppose in the value I have put :   152.36
 println "valor: " + factura.value   => return 15236.0

 //Suppose in the value I have put :   152,36
 println "valor: " + factura.value   => return 15236.0
```

}

How can I return as a decimal? I need 152.36

Comment: You can use the @BindUsing annotation on your 'value' property to ensure that the binding from your form to your entity is done as you expect it to.

ref (Grails 3.1): http://docs.grails.org/3.1.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#_the_bindusing_annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can use text input and cast it to BigDecimal

Change this

```
<input type="number" step="any" name="value" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="value" />
```

In your save method

```
try{
    params.value.toBigDecimal()
catch(e){
   // error
}
```